# SQL Server: statement in a batch all execute as one transaction?

Tags: sql-server

So I ran a SQL batch with a bunch of UPDATE statements:

```
UPDATE...;    
UPDATE...;    
UPDATE...;
```

Turns out the batch ran as a single transactions consequently many locks were created (our database monitoring software clearly shows that it was one big transaction) so apparently its similar to me writing BEGIN...COMMIT around the batch:

```
BEGIN TRANS;    
UPDATE...;    
UPDATE...;    
UPDATE...;    
COMMIT;
```

Is that really the case? Are batches always executed as one transaction? (I am not in 'explicit transaction' mode) and why is that, and can it be configured or is that just the behavior of SQL Server?

Would it change anything if I wrap every statement in a BEGIN..COMMIT, something like:

```
BEGIN TRANS;
UPDATE...;
COMMIT;     
BEGIN TRANS;
UPDATE...;
COMMIT;     
BEGIN TRANS;
UPDATE...;
COMMIT;
```

Thank You!

Comment: You probably have disabled autocommit. [`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Then after each statement changes are committed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are executing your UPDATEs from a SSMS Query Window, you can refactor your code to

```
BEGIN TRANS;    
UPDATE...;
GO    
UPDATE...;
GO    
UPDATE...;
GO    
COMMIT;
```

GO WILL make each UPDATE execute prior in its own batch in the order called, but won't be committed until the final COMMIT is called.

I have tested this via the following example that you can run for yourself in SSMS.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'BatchTest' )
    DROP TABLE dbo.BatchTest;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.BatchTest (
    id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    , col1 VARCHAR(50)
    , col2 VARCHAR(50)
    , col3 VARCHAR(50)
    , col4 VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

DECLARE @i INT = 1;
WHILE ( @i <= 100 ) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.BatchTest ( col1 ) VALUES ( 'col1_' + CAST ( @i AS VARCHAR(10) ) );
    SET @i += 1;
END
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.BatchTest ORDER BY id;

/*
    -- test tran/commit --
    -- manually select and execute the code below after the BatchTest has been created and populated with data --

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    GO

    BEGIN TRAN;
    UPDATE dbo.BatchTest SET col2 = 'col2_' + CAST ( id AS VARCHAR(10) );
    GO
    UPDATE dbo.BatchTest SET col3 = 'col3_' + CAST ( id AS VARCHAR(10) );
    GO
    UPDATE dbo.BatchTest SET col4 = 'col4_' + CAST ( id AS VARCHAR(10) );
    GO
    --COMMIT;
    ROLLBACK;

    SELECT * FROM dbo.BatchTest ORDER BY id;

*/
```

Please note the comments in the code about selecting and executing the tran/commit test.

The single ROLLBACK undoes all of the UPDATEs within the current transaction, regardless of the use of GOs, whereas COMMIT will commit them all. Obviously, you should do more your diligence and test against your data, but this might help with your locking issues.

Some follow-up reading in regard to SQL Server's use of GO and its intentions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank You. but what I meant to ask is more about SQL Server behavior: If I run batch - say a bunch of DML statements - are they all executed by default as a single transaction?

Comment: also, in your first code snippet, you've wrapped everything in a BEGIN..COMMIT and added Go between the statements. you're saying it wont be committed until the final COMMIT is called. But.. I'd get the same result if I don't add the GO in there, wouldn't I?

Comment: GO executes the previous statement and waits for it to complete before moving on to the next. This should help with some of your locking issues as not all updates will be firing at once. You are correct about the TRAN/COMMIT. It works the same regardless of the use of GO.

Comment: so what you're saying is, in my batch, without the GO, all those UPDATEs will be executing at once, not serially  (but not as one transaction, since i don't have an explicit BEGIN..COMMIT) so the GOs just control the timing

Comment: That is correct. I expect it may help with locking up your server's resources--not the TRAN--but that is really dependant on many factors, the largest being how much data is being updated. If there are a lot of rows, you'll want to consider breaking those up into smaller bites.

Comment: Your TRAN/COMMIT is the only way that I know of to ensure each update runs within its own transaction in the same query window.